# List contains buttons. On button click open controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

On my View, I have a List with three columns:

1. Application Number
2. Employee Code
3. Button

On click of a button, the corresponding Application Number and Employee Code should pass to a controller.

Whether to keep a button or Action Link and how to use it to pick corresponding application number and employee code?

I am using Razor.

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect r use ajax and stay on the same page? And what is the signature of the controller method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Want to redirect to another View.

Comment: Use `@Html.ActionLink()` adding the ApllicationNumer and EmployeeCode as route values. And style the `<a>` tag to look like a button if that's what you want.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please show a line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

in your view

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyController",
    new { appNo=Model.AppNumber, empCode = Model.EmpCode})
```

And in MyController

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int appNo, int empCode)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: When I am specifying controller name, it is passing model value as null. When I removed controller name, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass application number and employee code as route values to controller.

Like this:

```
@foreach(var row in Model)
{
    ...
    @Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", new { row.ApplicationNumber, row.EmployeeCode })
}
```

And the controller action method:

```
public ActionResult Action(int applicationNumber, int employeeCode)
{
   ...
}
```